# Custom ImageView on the map is not rotating along with MapView in iphone

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios6, mkmapview

Hi I am working on the map application. I am rotating the mapview and imageview, it is subview on the annotationView. Mapview rotation is perfect, but imageview is not rotating according to Mapview, and always points to North direction.

I am using below code for rotating imageview :

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation

{

static NSString *identifier = @"annView";

MKPinAnnotationView *annView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

annView=nil;
[annView setSelected:YES animated:NO];
if (annView == nil) 
{
    annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

MyAnnotation *myAnnotation=(MyAnnotation *)annotation;
NSString *details;
if ([myAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    //return nil;
}
else
{
    details=[myAnnotation annType];

}
NSLog(@"Details is  %@",details);
annView.canShowCallout = YES;

if([details isEqualToString:@"Current"])
{
    [[annView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    annView.animatesDrop=NO;
    annView.canShowCallout=YES;//pin3.png// Parking_Psymbol//dus2
    annView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    UIImage * locaterImage;
    locaterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Locatermap.png"];

    locaterImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:locaterImage];
    locaterImageView.frame = CGRectMake(-28, -4, 70, 70);

    //--------For animating imageview ---------------------

    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:2.0];
    //[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
           [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    //--------For animating imageview ---------------------
    [annView addSubview:locaterImageView];
}
```

And for rotating the MapView :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading

{

// Convert Degree to Radian and move the needle
float oldRad =  -manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
float newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;

CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRad];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRad];
theAnimation.duration = 0.5f;
[mapView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
self.mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
}
```

I googled, but i cant find my required answer. Please give any ideas to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is all this just to rotate the map so that is matches the real world? I.e. north on the map is really pointing north? If so, what you need to do is set the `MKMapView`'s `userTrackingMode` to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`

Comment: Why are you rotating the map? Do you want the map to turn so that north on the map points towards the north pole?